# Infinite loop in Stack, implemented as "Linked List"

Tags: c++, for-loop, linked-list, stack

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();

    void push(void *data);
    void *pop();
    void print();

protected:
    typedef struct Element
    {
        struct Element *next;
        void *data;

    }Element;

    Element *top;
};

Stack::Stack()
{
    top = NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while(top)
    {
        Element *elm = top->next;
        delete top;
        top = elm;
    }
}

void Stack::push(void *data)
{
    Element *elm = new Element;
    elm->data = data;
    elm->next = top;;
    top = elm;
}

void *Stack::pop()
{
    void *data;

    if(top==NULL) return data;

    data = top->data;

    Element *elm = top;

    top = elm->next;
    delete elm;
    return data;


}

void Stack::print()
{
    Element *elm = top;

    while(elm)
    {
        cout << *(static_cast<int *>(elm->data))<<" ";
        elm = elm->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Stack *st = new Stack;;

    int n1 = 10;
    int n2 = 20;
    int n3 = 30;
    int n4 = 40;
    int n5 = 50;

    st->push(&n1);
    st->push(&n2);
    st->push(&n3);
    st->push(&n4);
    st->push(&n5);
    st->print();

    cout << *(static_cast<int*>(st->pop()))<< " poped\n";
    cout << *(static_cast<int*>(st->pop()))<< " poped\n";

    st->print();

    cout << endl;

    system("pasue");
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, I am learning  this data structure to be implemented in this way, and this is my first attempt. Why it is entering to an infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? You've probably introduced circular reference, I betcha on stack size = 1. This class has many flaws in general.

Comment: It works well on my machine (g++ 4.6.3 on linux 3.2.0)

Comment: Where did you encounter the infinite loop? The only loop of your code is in `print` method. And it deosn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Turn on warnings for your compiler (for gcc: -Wall -Wextra) and fix the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
void *Stack::pop()
{
    void *data;
    //...
}
```

Initialize the variable before usage:

```
void *Stack::pop()
{
    void *data = NULL;
    //...
}
```

If you put the `pop` method in a loop to extract all the elements, it may never return `NULL` because uninitialzed variables can have any value (whatever was in the memory location before).

Answer (score 1):

You are returning garbage value

```
void *Stack::pop()
{
    void *data;

    if(top==NULL) return data;
```

At this `if(top==NULL) return data;` data points garbage
You should return NULL

```
if(top==NULL) return top;
```